# Mapping Opportunity Product to Order Product object

Tags: formula, formula-field, opportunity-lineitem

I'm spinning up `Contracts` and `Orders` within my organization and need to map fields from my `Opportunities` over to their place in the Contract/Order/Order Products objects.

I've successfully pulled over Product fields using a text lookup such as: `TEXT(PricebookEntry.Product2.Family)`
This has worked just fine on fields that are brought into the opportunity via the price book.

What I can't get to work (which has to just be a lookup issue) are a couple of fields that exist as custom **Opportunity Product** line fields. I've tried starting with OpportunityLineItem but that isn't working. All I need to do here is create a simple formula that does a lookup to this data. Any thoughts?

Comment: A formula will not work to pull in data from child records as there could be many so no way to know which to pull from. You could potentially use process builder to piece something together though

Comment: You'll need to add a bit more detail about what kind of data you're hoping to pull over if you want specific advice. There are a few different approaches out there to pull data up, but as Eric mentions, it's a many-to-one relationship so it's not entirely obvious.

Comment: The field I'm working on pulling in now is a simple picklist field that is located within the opportunity product line section. My reps denote whether the product being sold is "new" or a "renewal". (I'll auto-select this for them in the future). Given that a product could have either value, this field isn't located within the Products section.

When creating the Order Product lines I'm able to pull in all of the other individual line data, but just can't figure out the lookup formula to create for this one. If the value was "new" in the Opp, I want it to reflect "new" in the Order.